# How to annotate index on compound key with morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia, mongodb-java

I am using morphia github version 1.2.2. I know how to annotate index on one field on morphia entity, but is there a way to annotate index on compositon of two fields. For example what would be the annotation for the following class if I want to have a composite index on field a and b.

```
@Entity
public class TestClass
{
    @Property("a")
    private int fieldA;
    @Property("b")
    private int fieldB;
    //how to annotate index of compound key fieldA and fieldB using morphia index annotation?
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@Entity
@Indexes(@Index(name = "aAndB", value = "a, b"))
public class TestClass
{
    @Property("a")
    private int fieldA;
    @Property("b")
    private int fieldB;
    //how to annotate index of compound key fieldA and fieldB using morphia index annotation?
}
```

Giving the index a name is optional. You could also make the compound index unique.

Comment: using this approach, I get warning messages in the log saying I'm using deprecated methods. 
This is how I annotate my class:

@Indexes(@Index(value = Chat.USER_ID_1 + "," + Ch.USER_ID_2, unique = true))
public class Chat {}

Comment: The syntax has changed with Morphia 1.0: `@Indexes(@Index(fields = { @Field(Chat.USER_ID_1), @Field(Ch.USER_ID_2)}, options = @IndexOptions(unique = true)))`